# How to create a simple html server using express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fileserver

I'm new in node.js I want to create a simple express.js static file server, but I have some issues.
I have been installed express.js 4.2 globally like this:

```
npm install  -g express-generator
```

I have this code in httpsrv.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.listen(3000, function() { console.log('listening')});
```

I'm not sure is it ok  I guess it is not enough, but I cant run it it's failed with error: cannot find module 'express'.

I want to create a simple http server which can serve from specific folder("\public" e.g.) and I'm using .html language. I found on the internet a many bullshit, I don't want to use this .jade thing and I don't want to create a empty web app with express etc. I want express.js http server which can operate like Apache and can serve a static html pages first from a specified folder.
Can anybody help me on this, suggest a good article which is explain a step by step, because I'm beginner.

Comment: Have you followed the steps here: http://expressjs.com/guide.html

Comment: I don't think express-generator is what you need installed, you should run npm install -g express, and than try loading it.

Comment: I also have installed express 4.2, but I have been read express 4.x need this express-generator also.

Comment: ...where did that `httpsrv.js` come from?  It doesn't follow express 4.x conventions. It looks like it is from an older 3.x example.  The express generator creates `app.js` that exports much of what is needed and `npm start` launches the server. It doesn't look like you used the generator or you used it and...ignored the output?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're just trying to serve static files from a directory called "public", you might have luck with an app like this:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

var staticPath = path.join(__dirname, '/public');
app.use(express.static(staticPath));

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('listening');
});
```

You'll need to make sure Express is installed. You'll probably run `npm install express --save` in the same directory as the above JavaScript file. Once you're all ready, you'll run `node the_name_of_the_file_above.js` to start your server.

Comment: Now it almost good, but when I start the server and try to see in the browser, I get this message: "Cannot GET / ". I guess its only something path problem. My javascript server file is placed in the same "/public" directory what I want to serve is it a problem?

Comment: Change it to `path.join(__dirname, '/public')`

Comment: how to run the app on https and http both?

Comment: @JitendraPancholi It depends, but you can use the built-in `https` module to do this. Happy to find an example if you want more guidance.

Answer (score 12):

first install express module inspite of express-generator

```
npm install express
```

try this removing public

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname));
app.listen(3000, function() { console.log('listening')});
```

it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

This problem shouldn't even need any code or frameworks; install http-server from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server), navigate to the folder in the command prompt and run this command:

```
http-server
```

And it will spin up a lightweight http server and serve static content up from the folder immediately which can be viewed using http://localhost

Comment: you are not even answering the question.

Comment: His/her requirement was to set up a simple server to serve static pages from a folder; this package does exactly that. You don't need to use a framework like Express for this purpose.