# Cannot serve angular 2 index.html file from express server due to path relativity issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

[image: Fig 1]

This is my app folder structure with the angular-client folder 
[image]

The below picture shows the issue where when I server the index file of angular app from express server , all the gets are relative to the express server app.
[image]

This is index.js server code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');


app.listen(3000,function(){
console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});

app.get('/',function(req,res){
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'angular-client')+'/src/index.html');
});
```

Could anyone find a solution  ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a simple html server using express js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517753/how-to-create-a-simple-html-server-using-express-js)

Comment: I read the above question , its not the same . When serving the index file ,in the angular folder the js and css files refered are relative to the root express folder . But the path given are relative to the angular folder . I have checked many examples. All have the index file outside the src folder. Or they have two servers , one for angular and other folder node  , and they run independantly.

Comment: try with the path like "../../node_modules/*"

Answer (score 0):

The route in your image only handles `GET /` (and serves `index.html` as the response).

First, you need a route that catches `GET /styles.css`, for example. Then you need to have it serve the `styles.css` as the response.

[express.static](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) does both of these things for you (see the docs in the link).

Assuming you run `node server.js` from the `TODOMEANAPP` directory (as opposed to, say, `node TODOMEANAPP/server.js`), the following code should work:

```
app.use(express.static('angular-client'));
```

However, you'll have to change `href="styles.css"` to `href="src/styles.css"` and `src="systemjs.config.js"` to `src="src/systemjs.config.js"`.

Comment: Actually , that not all all the file calls in the index.html should be src/<filename> . But , what happens next is that the app components and modules are called relative to the server root and not angular root .

Comment: zone.js:1960 GET http://localhost:3000/src/app/app.module 404 (Not Found) . This is the error that I got .

Comment: From the express.static docs: "the path that you provide to the express.static function is relative to the directory from where you launch your node process". Suppose you run `node server.js` from `TODOMEANAPP`. Suppose you request `GET src/styles.css`. It'll hit `app.use`, `express.static` will append `src/styles.css` to `TODOMEANAPP/angular-client` and thus look for `TODOMEANAPP/angular-client/src/styles.css`, which is a file in your directory, so it'll serve that file as the response.

Comment: But if the files being served calls other files relative to its location , like the index.html file it creates a problem. I think bundling and extracting out the js files to a public folder and then serving this folder will resolve the issue .